# Why detail View is not showing?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I have this code in my `Index.tsx` file that currently shows a list of `Actors`. I want to show an actor's details by hitting the `Detail` button, but my problem is the detail view is not showing. Can anybody helps?:

```
<td>
   <button className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleDetails(item.Id)}>Detail</button>
</td>
```

That calls this method:

```
handleDetails(id: number) {
    this.renderPopUp();
}
```

That calls this method:

```
private renderPopUp() {
    return <Details id={this.state.activeId} />;
}
```

And already import this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router'
import * as models from "../../models"
import * as Modal from 'react-modal'
import { Details } from './Details'
```

And finally this is my `Details.tsx` file:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router'
import * as models from "../../models"

interface IDetailsState {
    actor: models.Actor;
    loading: boolean,
}

interface IDetailsProps {
    id: number
}

export class Details extends React.Component<IDetailsProps, IDetailsState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            actor: null,
            loading: true
        };
         alert('Hi');//This is not showing
        fetch('api/actors/get/' + this.props.id)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<models.Actor>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    actor: data,
                    loading: false
                });
            });
    }

    public render() {
        alert('HelloAgain');
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em>
              </p>
            : this.renderDetails(this.state.actor);
        return <div>
                   <h1>Actor Details</h1>
                   {contents}
               </div>;
    }

    private renderDetails(item: models.Actor) {
        return <div className='details'>
                   <label>Id</label>
                   <div>item.Id</div>
                   <label>Name</label>
                   <div>item.Name</div>
                   <label>Gender</label>
                   <div>item.Gender</div>
                   <label>Age</label>
                   <div>item.Age</div>
                   <label>Picture</label>
                   <div>item.Picture</div>
               </div>;
    }
}
```

**The main problem is `return <Details id={this.state.activeId} />;` is not calls the `Details.tsx` and I'm wondering why?  I added an alert, `alert('Hi');` above `fetch` and it is not showing also.**

Comment: try doing the fetch call inside componentDidMount

Comment: Ideally you should not call a `setState()` in side the `constructor()`, since the component has not rendered yet. But that should not be the main problem here. Are you getting the data after the API call? If not try to change it to `response => return response.json() as Promise<models.Actor>`. You could otherwise make the data fetching in `componentDidMount()`, to make the code a little more better.

Comment: @Gautam My problem is the `Details.tsx` is not calling. forget about API call, I added an alert `alert('Hi');` above `fetch` and it is not showing also.

Comment: @AbhayShiro Can you show how?

Comment: @Gautam The `Index` can't call `Details`. I don't know why?

Comment: @J.P If not even the `alert` that you printed above `fetch` is working, then it means that the call is not in the `constructor()` yet. Try checking whether you have any compilation errors or console errors.

Comment: @Gautam I haven't any console error.

Comment: public componentDidMount() {
  fetch('api/actors/get/' + this.props.id)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<models.Actor>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    actor: data,
                    loading: false
                });
            });
}

Please refactor it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue. You are not actually rendering the `Details` component.It is only being returned. That's why it is not getting rendered. On button click state should be changed and component rerendered with `Details`. Then, it shall work. 
Try the code below in `index.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Details }  from './details';

interface State {
   id: number;
   renderDetails: boolean;
}

export class Index extends React.Component<any, State> {

constructor(props: any, state: State){
    super(props, state);
    this.state ={
        id: 0,
        renderDetails: false
    }
}
public render() {
    let details = this.state.renderDetails ? <Details id={this.state.id}/> : null;
    return (
        <div>
            <td>
                <button className="action" onClick={this.handleDetails.bind(this, 1)}>Detail</button>
            </td>
            {details}
        </div>
    );
}

private handleDetails(id: number){
    this.setState({
        id: id,
        renderDetails: true
    })

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public componentDidMount() {
  fetch('api/actors/get/' + this.props.id)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<models.Actor>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    actor: data,
                    loading: false
                });
            });
}
```

Maybe you can try calling you API calls inside componentDidMount.
Please let me know. Open for discussion.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. It even didn't work for simple alert, `public componentDidMount() {
        alert('Hi');        
    }` Nothing works in `Details` tsx file.